# "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" After adding js to layout file

Tags: layout, adminform, wysiwyg

I am building a admin form which uses wysiwyg editor. So, I add the following xml statement to the corresponding layout file. However, I got this error: "http://127.0.0.1/magento/js/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I learnt from other posts on the Internet that I can get this file from the installation file downloaded from official website and put it the the js folder. However, I found that many extensions also use this file, but they don't have this problem. So, I want to ask if there is any way to solve this problem without copying "magento.css" file. Thank you in advance.

```
<handle>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setCanLoadTinyMce">
            <flag>1</flag>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>mage/adminhtml/variables.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>lib/flex.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>lib/FABridge.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>prototype/window.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js_css</type>
            <name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js_css</type>
            <name>prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js</name>
            <params/>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>magestore/bannerslider/tooltip.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>magestore/bannerslider/prototip.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</handle>
```

Comment: what would be a correct path to that file on your system ?

Comment: I am sorry that I make a mistake here. The file is gotten from the installation file downloaded from Magento official website.